# How lightnin-web-components are created ?. example: lightning-button,

Tags: lightning-web-components

HI Lightning web component developers. Can anyone tell how these components of salesforce was developed or can i get source code for reference to create few custom components of my own style.
I tried creating components by managed(code is hidden,attributes etc are not visible) and unmanaged (code is visible able to achieve,attributes etc are visible)package but couldn't succeed.  It will be useful to create a resuable component which doesn't exist in salesforce[If anyone suggests how the salesforce components was created.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button/example)[image: Image shows the the components of salesforce]

Answer (score 2):

The standard components are closed-source. You can't get at their source code. However, they are based on the [Lightning Design System](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/), which you can use. Simply find the component you want to replicate, and you'll find all the HTML you need to copy-paste. Additional changes (e.g. JavaScript), you'll have to implement yourself.

Comment: can you suggest similar packaging way like used in salesforce lwc components @sfdcfox

Comment: @vishnu I'm not sure what your question is. What's the purpose of packaging? Who is your target audience?

Comment: suppose i'm creating components of resuable type and want to share to different users. But source code  shouldn't be visible and all properties of that component should visible but not the code.So it can be used through visual studio like for ex: lightning-button. @sfdcfox

Comment: @vishnu I don't think that's an option. See [Migrate Access Controls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/48.0/lwc/migrate_access_controls) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Base Lightning Web Components have been open sourced recently:
[Github-Repo](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes)

The components have been transpiled to the c-namespace and so you can add them to your project as other components you have created. But that also means you have to maintain those components manually in case Salesforce updates the code.

Here is the direct deeplink to the components in the mentioned repo: [lwc](https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc)